# Setting a variable = to getElementById().innerHTML

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, getelementbyid

I've learned how when you set up code to look like, for example:

```
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = text;
```

that it will change the contents of id to be text;
But I also see sometimes that instead of setting the getElementById().innerHTML to something, it is reversed, setting a variable equal to getElementById().innerHTML and I don't see what the purpose of that is throughout the rest of the code.

Comment: You would do that if you want to get the content of an element (as HTML). What's so surprising about it?

Comment: It is useful sometimes, you know..

Comment: That's what I was thinking. Just the way this code I'm reading was written, I thought it was supposed to be going in a different direction and wasn't sure if I was just missing something or thinking too much into it when as you said, it's pretty straight forward.

Comment: Well, since we don't know the code you read, we can't say anything about that.

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = text` is meant to adjust the value of the element's inner HTML. This may be used to dynamically change an element's HTML.

`text = document.getElementById(id).innerHTML` is meant to get and store the value of the elements HTML. This would allow developers to have a cached reference to the DOM element's content should they want to insert it elsewhere in the page, check its value, etc.